# What does 'docker images ls' do?

Tags: docker

I looked up the docs to understand the difference between commands `docker image` (managing images) and `docker images` (list images). So the second option seems to be a shortcut for `docker image ls` which also lists images.

What I noticed is, when running `docker image ls` or `docker images` I get a list of all my images as expected, but when I accidentally mixed those two up and run  `docker images ls` I get an empty table without any entries:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

I would expect it either to be an invalid command since it is redundant or to show the same list of all my images.

So what does `docker images ls` actually show?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `docker image ls` lists the images
- `docker images` also lists the images
- `docker images ls` lists the images with the repository name **ls**. And as you dont have any images named **ls** it is returning an empty list.

Reference : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: the list is empty because you have no images named `ls`.

You can read about it in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#list-images-by-name-and-tag).