# is "docker images" an alias for "docker image ls" command?

Tags: docker

when I run `docker images` or `docker image ls` I always get the same result, also when I run `docker images --help` and `docker image ls --help` I notice that both have the same description: *list images*.

so it looks like they are the same. however I did not find any note in docker official docs that refer that `docker images` is an alias for `docker image ls`.

So is my guess correct (`docker images` is an alias for `docker image ls`) or is there a difference between them that I haven't noticed?

> **EDIT:** even that the answers of these two questions: [What does 'docker images ls' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104631/what-does-docker-images-ls-do) and [What is the difference between "docker images ls" and "docker image ls"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639624/what-is-the-difference-between-docker-images-ls-and-docker-image-ls) don't emphasize that `docker images` is an alias for `docker image ls`.
>
> But yes, they are the same (see [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) comment below): The two commands are **identical**. `docker images` was the original command before the cli was restructured.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'docker images ls' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104631/what-does-docker-images-ls-do)

Comment: The two commands are identical. `docker images` was the original command before the cli was restructured.

Comment: @Julia no, that question is different

Comment: @AmjedOmar: The title of that question isn't helpful, but I believe it answers your question.

Comment: @Julia will, it kinda answers the question, but it doesn't emphasize that `docker images` is an alias for `docker image ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was not intended to make it an alias but it become alias later. Both have same structure for passing parameters/arguments and will show same result in all the cases.

If you want to read more about docker images from official document here is the link : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/

Comment: Now I totally agree that both commands are identical. but I'm not sure about: *it will becomes an alias later* because also maybe, one of them will be depreciated then removed in future.

Comment: There's no deprecation, it would break too many scripts.